# Android OnGestureListener onScroll MotionEvent

Tags: android, gesturedetector

I have a problem with the onScroll event of the OnGestureListener.

the method signature is as follows:

```
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY);
```

The problem is that the MotionEvent e1 seems to be always the same after the first scrolling.
When I in example do e1.getX() on the first srcolling it returns 100. when I then stop scrolling and start a second scroll on a different spot of the screen, it also gives 100. only the MotionEvent e2 changes it's value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`e1` will always be the initial motion event for a touch event (The ACTION_DOWN event). `e2` is the current motion event.

Comment: well, but when i do a second scroll, i mean, when i stop scrolling by releasing the finger from the screen, and then start a second scrolling e1 still remains the same... shouldn't e1 always be the initial touch when scrolling and not the first touch at all?

Comment: Can you verify whether the hashcode is the same or different between two separate scrolls.

Comment: as it seems, i have a bug in my framework when buffering touchevents... when i use the native OnTouchListener it works...